# $.getJSON inside other $.getJSON order of values problem

Tags: javascript, json

Im trying connect to a JSON API through `$.getJSON`... Show it with a for loop...  Take a value for the JSON and show other JSON where it correspond.

The problem is that first show all the values from the first JSON and after shows all the values from the second... Even if one is inside the other.

```
var urlSearch='https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch'+'?apiKey='+key+'&query='+buscar.value+'&number=2';
body.innerHTML= ' ';

$.getJSON(urlSearch,(data)=>{
  for(var k in data.results){

    var id=data.results[k].id;
    var imagen=data.results[k].image;
    var titulo=data.results[k].title;
    var urlInfo='https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/'+id+'/information'+'?apiKey='+key;

    body.innerHTML+= '<div id=kpi>';
    body.innerHTML+='<div><img src="'+imagen+'"></div>';
    body.innerHTML+='<div>'+titulo+'</div>';
    $.getJSON(urlInfo,(data2)=>{
      body.innerHTML+='<div>'+data2.summary+'</div>';
    });

    body.innerHTML+='</div>';
  } 

});
```

Comment: The callback function passed to `$.getJSON` is executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is asynchronous, meaning the code that follows after your call to $.getJSON will execute before the code in the callback function you send to it. If you want to wait until everything is loaded, you should do something like this

```
$.getJSON(urlSearch,(data)=>{
for(var k in data.results){
        
        var id=data.results[k].id;
        var imagen=data.results[k].image;
        var titulo=data.results[k].title;
        var urlInfo='https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/'+id+'/information'+'?apiKey='+key;

        $.getJSON(urlInfo,(data2)=>{
            body.innerHTML+= '<div id=kpi>';
            body.innerHTML+='<div><img src="'+imagen+'"></div>';
            body.innerHTML+='<div>'+titulo+'</div>';
        
            body.innerHTML+='<div>'+data2.summary+'</div>';
        
            body.innerHTML+='</div>';
        });
    } 

});
```

This way the innerHTML is only set once when all the values are available

Comment: You need to use `let` to declare the variables. Otherwise, all the closures will share the same variables.